# Qt: How to change Android application name?

Tags: android, qt

How can I change name of my Qt Android application? [Image Link](http://s2.postimg.org/e3wffgjgp/img0.png).
Application name looks other names. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already changed the application name successfully. Now you need to change the activity name. (Launcher icons on android are actually links to activities, not to the "application").

The property is located directly below the application name (marked blue):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is true answer.

Comment: Also when I compiled my application, name of .apk file is 'QtApp-release-signed.apk'. How can I change this name? (ex: MyApp.apk).

Comment: @İbrahim - how about just rename the apk file?